# Wordpress custom category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I am stuck at creating custom blog category page. I would like to ask, what do I need to add to this code to make it show only the posts from currently viewed category?

```
<?php

function getblogpostsmain($atts, $content = null) {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'posts' => 1,
   ), $atts));

   $return_string .= '<div class="main">';
   query_posts (array('orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' , 'showposts' => $posts));
   if (have_posts()) :
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $return_string .= '<h1 class="title"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'  </a></h1><div class="infoblog">Posted on '.get_the_date().' in '.get_the_category_list(__( ', ', 'twentyeleven' ) ).'</div> ';
    $return_string .= '<p class="excerpt">' . get_the_excerpt() . '';
endwhile;
   endif;
   $return_string .= '</div>';

   wp_reset_query();
   return $return_string;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add `'category' => 'categoryName'` to your `query_posts` array.
More information in [my blog post](http://en.nickolaj-sarry.info/2014/04/creating-custom-post-type-and-widget.html)

Comment: I am not sure how to implement it. Even though i tried it still ignores it.

Comment: may be [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/only-show-posts-of-current-category) WP forum theme will help you? in this WP forum theme discuss similar problem